# Liip imagine bundle problems with resizing

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, liipimaginebundle

My error that I get when I run the command `php bin/console liip:imagine:cache:resolve public/images/5e57925688ede894214180.png --filter=thumbnail` is `

> public/images/5e57925688ede894214180.png[thumbnail] (failed) Source
>   image not resolvable "public/images/5e57925688ede894214180.png" in
>   root path(s) "/app/public"

`In the conntroller I try with this line of code

> ```
>        $resizeImage = $this->filterService->getUrlOfFilteredImage($this->kernel->getProjectDir().$image->getUrl(), $filter[$i]);
> ```

I get this error:

> Source image not resolvable "/app/public/images/dw-5e5e15d6a52f8.png"
>   in root path(s) "/app/public"

**routes/liip_imagine.yaml file look like this**

```
 _liip_imagine:
        resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.yaml"
```

**`packages/liip_imagine.yaml look like this`**

```
liip_imagine:
  driver: imagick #options: imagick or gd
  resolvers:
    default:
      web_path: ~

  filter_sets:
    cache: ~

    # the name of the "filter set"
    thumbnail:
      # adjust the image quality to 75%
      quality: 75

      # list of transformations to apply (the "filters")
      filters:

        # create a thumbnail: set size to 120x90 and use the "outbound" mode
        # to crop the image when the size ratio of the input differs
        thumbnail:
            size: [256, 256]
            mode: outbound
            allow_upscale: true

    large_m:
      filters:
        scale:
            dim: [2048,2048]
```

Pictures are in path public/images

Comment: And can you confirm that the image is at the location mentioned and that the process has reading rights to it? `ls /app/public/images/dw-5e5e15d6a52f8.png`

Comment: Yes the path was the problem, the path must go images/dw-5e5e15d6a52f8.png without public and then it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path was the problem the path must go `images/dw-5e5e15d6a52f8.png` without `public` in the front of the path